# LINQ select MonthId and MonthName from DateTime column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having trouble selecting MonthId and MonthName from a DateTime column in db.
I've tried this. It compiles but runtime error
"linq to entities does not recognize the method 'System.String.ToString()'"

```
var months = bookings.Select(c => new { 

                MonthId = c.ActualEta.Value.Month,
                MonthName = c.ActualEta.Value.Month.ToString("MMMM")
        }).ToList();
```

Anyone? ActualEta is an nullable datetime here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var months = bookings
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new { 
        MonthId = c.ActualEta.Value.Month,
        MonthName = c.ActualEta.Value.Month.ToString("MMMM")
    }).ToList();
```

Note the `AsEnumerable()`, this essentially converts the query from LinqToEntities to LinqToObjects, allowing you to use non-SQL methods like `ToString()`.

Comment: Example:  "c.ActualEta.Value.ToString("MMMM")", without "Month" property. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var months = bookings.Select(c => new { 
     MonthId = ((DateTime)c.ActualEta.Value).Month,
     MonthName = ((DateTime)c.ActualEta.Value).ToString("MMMM")
}).ToList();
```